# How can I add a decorative hologram to the Microsoft Hololens's catalog?

Tags: hololens

The Microsoft Hololens comes with an app tile called Holograms that is red.  If you pick it you get a catalog of holographic decorations you can scatter in space.

I would like to create my own animated hologram and add it to that catalog.

I followed the instructions at [Holograms 100](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_100) to create an animation in Unity which I can install via a USB cable (and after a few seconds it crashes the Hololens leading to a reboot; I suspect I'm doing too much math).  Unfortunately the animation appears to always fill the viewport rather than exist in a fixed space like the decorative holograms.

What changes do I need to make to create a hologram that appears in the built-in catalog and functions like those holograms?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment it is not possible to add any other 'holograms' in the `Holograms` app.

Any app that you would create will run in its own holographic space thus removing all the holograms you pinned from the Holograms app.

As you could expect, you are not the only one wanting this so, at this point I recommend you add a feature request using the feedback app. The more requests the more chances to actually get this feature in the future.

Comment: Any news about adding holograms  in the "holographic world/desktop" ?